# rspec: key not found: :example_id

Tags: rspec

I was getting:

```
> rspec
/Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1085:in `fetch': key not found: :example_id (KeyError)
    from /Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1085:in `block (2 levels) in last_run_statuses'
    from /Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1082:in `each'
    from /Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1082:in `inject'
    from /Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1082:in `block in last_run_statuses'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by deleting the temporary examples files:

```bash
rm tmp/rspec_examples.txt
```